# Different path to Notifications on iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, path, notifications

In my app I'm using the code below to get user to Notifications screen when he taps a button.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID"]];
```

This works ok, on iPhone and iPod, but it doesn't work on iPad.

Any ideea?

Thanks

Edit: Application is not universal.

Comment: It works on my iPad when entering the URL in Safari. Could it be a version issue?

Comment: it is a version issues. tester was using 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It is the iOS version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about the iOS version - check if you have iOS 5 installed on your devices. From my point of view, this command does not work on iOS 4.